# How to check if canvas was updated with Fabric.JS?

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

I am currently working on Auto Save module and I have to perform Auto Save process only if any changes made on canvas So, How can I identify the changes?

I have reach two approaches:

1. By comparing json

   - For example, when canvas load then I'll store blank canvas json of default atrributes in a variable and if any object/element is added/modified/removed in canvas then I'll update the canvas json and then compare updated canvas json with stored canvas json from variable.
2. Through fabric.js canvas events

   - For example, If any event is called of fabric.js

I didn't get any idea that which one is better approach or if there is a better way to detect canvas changes.

Can anyone help me please? It would really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad. "Best" is subjective and depends on the situation. Please see [ask], then provide some code for us to discuss.